# Disable systemd XDG autostart generator

Tags: systemd

`systemd-xdg-autostart-generator` is quite noisy in logs (it tries to parse files that aren't suffixed `.desktop`, and takes issue with some lines even in ones that are, and are provided by their package) and I don't use it, so I may as well disable it.

Its `man 8` page claims it's in `/usr/lib/systemd/system-generators`, but it isn't. How can it be disabled?

Answer (score 3):

`systemd-xdg-autostart-generator` is a user unit in
`/usr/lib/systemd/user-generators/`

`chmod a-x /usr/lib/systemd/user-generators/systemd-xdg-autostart-generator` stops the log messages. It probably has other effects as well, but none of them seem to affect me.  YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Bumped into [this link](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2015/09/msg00003.html), make sure to read `man systemd.generator`

Document suggested way to mask a generator (unlikely to be overwritten by package update):

```
mkdir /etc/systemd/user-generators
cd /etc/systemd/user-generators
ln -sf /dev/null systemd-xdg-autostart-generator
```

There are also other directories to do this, check out the doc.